# Using Thread.Sleep in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, sleep

I want to execute the following

```
MainPage = new ContentPage
{
    Content = new StackLayout
    {
        Children =
        {
            new Button
            {
                Text = "Thread.Sleep",
                Command = new Command(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    MainPage.Animate("", x => MainPage.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(x, x, x));
                }),
            },
            new Button
            {
                Text = "Task.Run + Thread.Sleep",
                Command = new Command(async () =>
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
                    MainPage.Animate("", x => MainPage.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(x, x, x));
                })
            },
            new Button
            {
                Text = "Device.StartTimer",
                Command = new Command(() => Device.StartTimer(
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                    () =>
                    {
                        MainPage.Animate("", x => MainPage.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(x, x, x));
                        return false;
                    })),
            },
        }
    }
};
```

I included `System.Threading` and `System.Threading.Tasks`, but I still get

> The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context.

[This site](http://www.xforms-kickstarter.com/#timer-never-miss-an-action) suggests that `Thread.Sleep` can be used in `Xamarin.Forms`. I have this in a shared project, not a PCL.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` should be avoided while using almost all UI frameworks (WinForms/WPF/Xamarin.Forms/Silverlight/...) as it freezes the UI thread and hangs the UI.

Comment: It is only for demonstration purposes, but thanks for your addition.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**If you want to wait**

asynchronously: `await Task.Delay(10000);`

synchronously: `Task.Delay(10000).Wait();`

But please try to avoid blocking the UI thread to ensure a good user experience and keep your app responsive.

**Using Thread.Sleep in Xamarin.Forms**

There are two Xamarin.Forms templates:

- Xamarin.Forms Portable Class Library

  Because of the PCL subset mechanism, you have no chance to get `Thread.Sleep`.

  **Update 2017:** PCLs are deprecated, now. If you use .netstandard 2.0, you can use `Thread.Sleep` as you are used to it.
- Xamarin.Forms Shared Project

  This Template contains different platforms that do not support `Thread.Sleep`. Windows UWP, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS support it, Windows Phone 8.1, and Windows 8.1 not. If you unload/delete the 2 projects, the solution builds. (don't forget using System.Threading; in your App.cs)

Comment: You are right that the UI thread should not get blocked. Here it is only for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Do you have an idea why `Thread` isn't recognized? On the linked page it seems that it somehow works.

Comment: I think you don't have `Thread.Sleep` because of a different PCL profile of your Core library. The more supported platforms you select in the PCL, the less supported classes / functions you can use.

Comment: Any ideas where this can be changed?

Comment: If you use a `Shared Library` instead of a `Portable Class Library`, it should work. But be aware, that some platforms simply don't support `Thread.Sleep` (e.g. WinPhone 8.1)

Comment: I tried it in a new `Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Shared)` and I get the same behavior. Strange ...

Comment: This is because the Template contains different platforms that do not support `Thread.Sleep`. Windows UWP, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS support it, Windows Phone 8.1, and Windows 8.1 not. if you unload/delete the 2 projects, the solution builds. (don't forget `using System.Threading;` in your App.cs.

Comment: That is the solution. Please edit you answer and I'll give you the tick.

Comment: I summarized it in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use

```
await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
```

if you want to put a delay in your thread.

For blocking you can do

```
Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Wait();
```

Comment: You could do that, but that is different from the example I want to try. The thread should get blocked with the first button not delayed. Do you have an idea what I'm missing? A reference in the sub projects?

Comment: @testing:- Updated my answer to block it. Please check