# Start two parallel tasks with Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

In this code `Parallel.ForEach` is not waiting. Seconds elapsed is immediately returning 0. This code is in a PCL:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    Task taskA = new Task(ExecuteTaskAAsync);
    Task taskB = new Task(ExecuteTaskBAsync);
    taskList.Add(taskA);
    taskList.Add(taskB);

    Parallel.ForEach(taskList, t => t.Start());

    watch.Stop();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Seconds Elapsed: " + watch.Elapsed.Seconds);
}

private async void ExecuteTaskAAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Task A: [{0}]", i + 1);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Finished Task A!");
}

private async void ExecuteTaskBAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Task B: [{0}]", i + 1);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Finished Task B!");
}
```

Responsible for this behavior seems to be `t.Start()`, which starts a new thread and `Parallel.ForEach` has finished. I also tried it by using `Task` as return type and this code:

```
Parallel.Invoke(async() => await ExecuteTaskAAsync(), async() => await ExecuteTaskBAsync());
```

Again seconds elapsed is immediately returning 0. How can I run both tasks parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parallel is working just fine - it's *starting* both tasks in parallel, just as your code is asking it to. It's just not waiting for those tasks to complete (and even if it was, those tasks aren't waiting for your `async void` methods to complete).

Since you're dealing with asynchronous tasks, what you really want is *asynchronous concurrency*, not *parallel concurrency*. They're both kinds of *concurrency* (doing more than one thing at the same time), but parallelism is about spawning multiple threads, whereas asynchrony is about freeing up the current thread.

Asynchronous concurrency works by using `Task.WhenAll`, as such:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
  watch.Start();

  Task taskA = ExecuteTaskAAsync();
  Task taskB = ExecuteTaskBAsync();

  await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB);

  watch.Stop();
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Seconds Elapsed: " + watch.Elapsed.Seconds);
}

private async Task ExecuteTaskAAsync()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Task A: [{0}]", i + 1);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
  }

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Finished Task A!");
}

private async Task ExecuteTaskBAsync()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Task B: [{0}]", i + 1);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
  }

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Finished Task B!");
}
```

Also note that I changed the existing `async void` methods to `async Task`; this is because `async void` is unnatural and should be only used for event handlers. See my MSDN article on [async best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more info.

As a final note, [you should never use the `Task` constructor](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html). I explain in detail on my blog, but it comes down to: there's *always* a better alternative.

Comment: The goal of my code was to have multiple threads working parallel so that I can see how it behaves when a single source (in this case `Debug.WriteLine`) is accessed. Is this goal reached with your corrected version?

Comment: No; the code I posted will all run on the UI thread. If you want to test multithreaded code, then use `Parallel` but remove all `async`/`await` and use `Thread.Sleep` instead of `Task.Delay`.

Comment: [`Thread.Sleep`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35767643/using-thread-sleep-in-xamarin-forms) isn't available in my environment (Portable Class Library). I'll try it with `Device.StartTimer` or `Task.Delay(1000).Wait();`. How do I use `Parallel` then here? Especially when not using the `Task` constructor.

Comment: @testing: `Parallel.Invoke(() => ExecuteTaskA(), () => ExecuteTaskB());`